# UPPAAL is not showing trace if the property is not satisfied

Tags: formal-verification, uppaal

I am using UPPAAL 4.1.24 for modeling a simple system composed of 1 main process and 3 observer processes. The main process uses a broadcast channel which is listened to by the observer processes. I have enabled `Options -> Diagnostic Trace -> Some`.

Now every time I check for a property by a query from the verifier, I can see the trace and replay it in the Trace box under the Simulator tab. However, it only works for the properties which are getting satisfied. If a property given by a query is not satisfied then the Trace does not get updated and I can not see the trace for that 'Not Satisfied" property.

Any idea?

Comment: What kind of property are you trying?

Comment: Some reachability properties

Comment: If some state is not reachable (`E<>` property is not satisfied), what trace do you expect?

Comment: I am expecting a trace that shows, until which state it was able to reach in the transition diagram. Not sure if it's technically possible or not.

Comment: But there can be many such states. From your reply, I have an impression that you are probably looking for deadlock property `E<> deadlock` which finds states without successors.